# permutation with 3 cycles

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I am supposed to find the number of permutations on a set of {1,2....n} with two fixed points and three cycles.
I have a trouble solving the second part - finding the number of permutations with three cycles. I think I should divide the set into three non-empty sets with the minimum of one element and its permutations, but I am not sure how to continue from there.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: "with the minimum of *one* element"..doesn't that minimum result in fixed points?

Comment: I suspect that the cycles are meant to be disjoint. Is that correct?

Comment: Does a fixed point count as a cycle (of length $1$)? If so, then the question amounts to counting the number of ways to choose two points (to be the fixed points) and then arrange the remaining $n-2$ points in a single cycle.

Comment: @AndreasBlass So I have to find all possible two fixed points - C(2,n) and then multiply it by the number of possible arrangements that create one cycle - and that is ((n - 2) - 1)!, do I understand it right?

Comment: @drhab yes, they are meant to be disjoint

Comment: @MrsRobot Your comment looks correct, except that I think the usual notation for the number of ways to choose $2$ points out of $n$ is not $C(2,n)$ but $C(n,2)$ or (even more commonly) $\binom n2$.